# Calling function inside a variable

Tags: javascript

I am using a plugin JS and need to call a function in it.

It is having functions inside a variable like,

```
var win = window;
var Page = function(pageOptions, callback) {
    function abc(){
           --------
     }
     function xyz(){
         ------
     }

};
win.Sales = {
    Page: Page
};
```

Now, I need to call a function abc(). How can I call it.
Already tried with `win.Sales.page.abc();`.

Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just say `win.Sales.Page` it will call the function. since Page contains the reference to a function.

Comment: @Sharma: I need to call abc() in it. Anyway I did what u suggested. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant call function `abc` since it is declared as a private member of the function referenced by variable `Page`.

If you want to call the function You have to make it as a property of the variable `Page`.

```
var Page = function(){
    .........
    .........
    .........
}

Page.abc = function(){
}
```

But there is another problem of variable scoping like if there is another variable x defined in function `Page` and used inside function `abc`, it will not work.

Anyway since you've said it is a js plugin I do not think it will be possible for you to change the function `Page`. So the answer will be No you cannot do that.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with your configuration because the functions are *local* or *private*.

You should make them accessible globally like:

```
var Page = function(...) {
    ...
};

Page.abc = function() {
    ...
};
```

That way, `abc` is a property of `Page`, and you can then access it like `Page.abc` and execute it like `Page.abc()`. Functions are basically also objects so they can have properties too.

Comment: Its a plugin for drawing some charts. I cannot change it and also I see that Page is getting declared in win.Sales.

Comment: @Max: Then you're out of luck I think, because the idea of those private variables/functions is that you cannot access them outside.